# What's the best way to talk to a database while using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, database, orm, sinatra

As I understand it, the Sinatra framework, unlike Rails, does not provide an ORM. In that case, how do you talk to a DB in a Sinatra app? Or is Sinatra only for apps that don't use a DB?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you like ActiveRecord, use that. Or something else. Datamapper, for instance. For AR with SQLite, this works:

```
require 'rubygems' # may not be needed, depending on platform
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end

get '/' do
  Article.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database => "hw.db"
  )
  Article.first.title
end
```

Comment: since 'activerecord' is deprecated use 'require active_record' instead.

Answer (score 63):

If you're using Sinatra, I can't recommend [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) highly enough.  I have a couple Rails apps where I'm stuck with ActiveRecord, and I'm constantly cursing its shortcomings and design flaws.  If you're on Sinatra, DataMapper is a very practical choice.

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require "datamapper"

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3::memory:")

class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,    Integer, :serial => true
  property :title, String
end

Post.auto_migrate!
first_post = Post.new
first_post.title = "First!"
first_post.save

get "/" do
  Post.get(1).title
end
```

Comment: when you use 'DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3::memory")' , is that an im-memory db? How would you persist that to disk, or how would you open an existing sqlite db file?

Comment: `DataMapper.setup(:default,  "sqlite3:path/to/db/file.db")`

Comment: I'm happy to see foreign key constraints in there (which isn't in Active Record).  Thanks.

Comment: require 'data_mapper'

Comment: Also, change the `property :id,    Integer, :serial => true` line to `property :id,    Serial`

Comment: I don't think so. DataMapper's last update is on 2011-10-13, today is 2019-3-15.  it's deprecated, I think. ActiveRecord is rapidly under development and maintenance.

Comment: Sure, but also this answer was written in 2009?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you how to communicate with a database, you may choose either one of the ORMs or some NoSQL adapter. There are many options available, some of them were made specially for Sinatra:

For example, there is [Sinatra ActiveRecord Extension](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord)
Originally created by Blake Mizerany, creator of Sinatra
It extends Sinatra with ActiveRecord helper methods and Rake tasks

Another option is [Sinatra Sequel Extension](https://github.com/rtomayko/sinatra-sequel).
This small extension adds database configuration, migrations, and Sequel adapters right into Sinatra.

Or sinatra-redis, or sinatra-mongo, and so on. Just search for what you want.

But you may as well freely use any independent library, check out the [Sinatra Recipes on databases](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/models), where is listed a couple of examples of how to use popular database mappers with Sinatra. Although it is mentioned there that the suggested practice for this is using DataMapper, I suspect that this is a mere preference, because nothing in Sinatra itself suggests this.