# Error loading Active Record gem with sinatra app using RVM

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, sinatra, rvm

I set up a project level RVM gemset for a sinatra app I am starting that will connect to a local database with Active Record. In order to test it I tried to run the below test app:

test.rb

```
require 'rubygems' # may not be needed, depending on platform
require 'sinatra'
require 'activerecord'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end

get '/' do
  Test.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database => "hw.db"
  )
  Test.first.content
end
```

(Taken from the answer to this question: [What's the best way to talk to a database while using Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777724))

When I run `ruby -rubygems test.rb` I get this error:

```
/Users/[user]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- activerecord (LoadError)
```

I've already installed the Active Record gem and it shows up in `gem list` and `rvm current` displays the correct gemset. I am new to RVM and I think this is something to do with the it not having the correct load path but I feel like I've set everything up correctly so I'd appreciate suggestions on what's wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I can tell require 'activerecord' has been deprecated. Try using

```
require 'active_record'
```

instead.

Comment: Why they dont rename the gem to active_record? This made me lose a lot of time, :(

Comment: Gem names tend to not correlate to how they are loaded as dependencies. Just looking at my project's `Gemfile` I can see multiple conventions in place, none of which are consistent. For example, `capybara-webkit` VS `database_cleaner`.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server after changing to avoid getting the error persisting!

Answer (score 0):

**If you have not already installed the activerecord gem, you will also get that error:**

Open a command prompt and run these commands in the terminal:

```
#Find if the active record gem is already installed on your computer:
gem query --local

#See the downloadable gems, and see if activerecord is still available:
gem query --remote --name-matches activerecord

#Install your gem:
gem install --remote activerecord

#See if it installed successfully and is in the installed gem list:
gem query --local
```

Here is some code that uses the ActiveRecord gem to see if everything is configured right:

```
#Ruby code
require 'active_record'
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dog_tags
end
puts "activerecord gem is installed";
```

If everything is working, it will print "activerecord gem is installed" without any errors.