# rackup cannot load activerecord

Tags: ruby, rack, faye

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error loading Active Record gem with sinatra app using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981576/error-loading-active-record-gem-with-sinatra-app-using-rvm)

I have a Faye app, in which I'd like to make use of ActiveRecord. I have this in my faye.ru:

```
require "rubygems"
require "faye"
require "sqlite3"
require "activerecord"

... other code
```

And I want to start it via: `rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production`

This fails with the following error: `/home/tempus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- activerecord (LoadError)`. If I run `rvm current` , I get: `ruby-1.9.3-p125@pno`. If I do a ls on the rvm dir for this gemset, I can see that activerecord is indeed installed:

```
actionmailer-3.2.2    builder-3.0.0              hike-1.2.1            polyglot-0.3.3   sprockets-2.1.2
actionpack-3.2.2      cookiejar-0.3.0            http_parser.rb-0.5.3  rack-1.4.1       sqlite3-1.3.5
activemodel-3.2.2     em-http-request-1.0.2      i18n-0.6.0            rack-cache-1.2   thor-0.14.6
activerecord-3.2.2    em-socksify-0.1.0          journey-1.0.3         rack-ssl-1.3.2   tilt-1.3.3
activeresource-3.2.2  erubis-2.7.0               json-1.6.6            rack-test-0.6.1  treetop-1.4.10
activesupport-3.2.2   eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4  mail-2.4.4            rails-3.2.2      tzinfo-0.3.32
addressable-2.2.7     faye-0.8.1                 mime-types-1.18       railties-3.2.2   yajl-ruby-1.1.0
arel-3.0.2            faye-websocket-0.4.4       multi_json-1.2.0      rdoc-3.12
```

I cannot understand why it would say that it cannot find activerecord. Any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though the gem is called `activerecord`, the class is called `ActiveRecord`, which converts to `active_record` in snake case:

```
require 'active_record'
```

Comment: Same issue with activesupport and brethren..

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server after changing to avoid getting the error persisting!